# stripe SessionCreateOptions not persisting client_reference_id that is passed to it

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

Just migrated to Stripe.com. I am creating a checkout session programmatically. See code snippet below. When I test, the User.Identity.GetUserId() comes back with a value and it is sent to stripe. However, when end user completes the payment, Stripe.com is not sending back the client_reference_id (it is null) in the event checkout.session.completed that I am listening to.

I get back my client_reference_id when I do payment links (send via querystring)

What am I doing wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SendToCheckout(ProcessPaymentViewModel model)
{
    StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _apiSecret;

    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        ClientReferenceId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
        SuccessUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + "/PaymentComplete",
        CancelUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + "/Subscribe",
        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
        {
            new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                Price = model.PriceId,
                Quantity =long.Parse(model.Quantity)
            },
        },
        Mode = "payment",
    };
    var service = new SessionService();
    var session = service.Create(options);

    return Redirect(session.Url);
}
```

reviewed stripe.com documentation. It appears I am setting it correctly. The other questions posted is one is really not answered and the other one says it should be in that webhook event. I dumped the values and it should client_reference_id: null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared looks correct and it's almost certain that you are not setting a value when you think you are.

The best path forward is to hardcode a value in your code and you should see that it works as expected and that the problem is the value you put in. What I would do is hardcode `AAAA`, confirm it's there, and then concat `AAAA` and the value in your variable and another string like `AAAA-<userid>-BBBB` and see that you get `AAAA--BBBB` because your string is null or empty.

This isn't a Stripe bug, that feature works as expected and is used widely but I've tested it quickly to confirm.

You can also look at the response on the Session creation after your code and just print `session.ClientReferenceId` and see that it's null right now.

Comment: I will test your plan out tomorrow and let you know. FWIW: I have data dump in production and client_reference_id is currently null on the webhook.

Comment: I found the root cause. I took off the [AllowAnonymous] attribute for good measure since my user is already logged in.

The problem was that on cshtml page, my form tag for the postback URL used a configuration value. In production, I accidentally left off the "s" on the "https". Thus, whenever it would post, I would get "are you sure? connection is unsafe". I am thinking through that process, the client_reference_id would not be correctly set or be dropped.

The previously posted code works with no modifications. Changing the postback URL in the form tag to "https" fixed my issue.